# How i get the values of the controls in a dataTrigger, DatagridTemplateColumn WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I saw this example in a post a few days ago.

```
    <Window x:Class="DataGridWithMultipleTypesPerColumn.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ControlTypes}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Control Type" Binding="{Binding}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actual Control">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="TextBox">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBox Text="Default Text"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CheckBox">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <CheckBox Content="Check Box"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Content="Button"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I want to get the value of this control, if control is a Chekcbox i need that value, i'm trying with a foreach but i dont get use the correct cast for each item.

Please i need your help, what can i do that?

Thanks !

Comment: you'd use binding inside of that template to do all the work, binding the various properties of the checkbox to properties in whatever data object you're using.

Comment: i do not this code, just i got for internet because this was what I needed for my application, can you give an example of how to do what you recommend, Thanks, i estimate it so much! this is my email filanderucles@hotmail.com

Comment: so you grabbed random code you don't understand off the internet, then want advice on how to use the random code from the internet?  You'll need to post a lot more information: what you're doing, what you've done, what isn't working, etc, so people can help you. See: http://www.sscce.org/